# How to export WMS source as XYZ Tiles?

Tags: qgis, wms, getcapabilities, xyz-tiles

I'm using a WMS source map from here:

https://geoserver9.esdm.co.uk/OrdnanceSurvey/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=OSLicensed2&TILED=true&SRS=EPSG:27700&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

My project CRS is set to EPSG:27700, and this is also shown at the bottom right.

I've set DPI Mode to 'off' in the WMS Source properties.

When I view this layer in QGIS ever, everthing is straight as in gridlines are perpendicular. But when Generate XYZ Tiles, the output is distorted (See pic below)

[image]

In the Debugging pane I can see the requests:

https://geoserver9.esdm.co.uk/OrdnanceSurvey/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=OSLicensed2&STYLES=&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image/png8&SRS=EPSG:27700&TILED=true&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&BBOX=400000,432640,400640,433280

How can I get QGis to save the received tiles with no transformation, no scaling or otherwise? They are perpendicular at least but in the past I've tried and it rotated them as well.

Comment: To get no distortions in the xyz tiles over the WMS image you'll need to keep the tile resolutions in the map canvas to the resolutions defined in the GetCapabilities ~ `<Resolutions>2000.0 1000.0 500.0 250.0 100.0 50.0 25.0 10.0 5.0 2.5 1.0 0.5 0.25 </Resolutions>`